# Htaccess multi doman with sub domain only

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I'm trying to host a sub domain of another website on my hosting because of compatibility.

I have a.com and api.b.com pointing to my server. Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is a.com to have its default behavior but api.b.com to be rewritten to a folder called api. Which is located in the root of a.com

Everything I've tried either does nothing or give me a 500 error. A lot of the people that had similar issues on this website their solutions did not work for me.

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Thanks,

Hans

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 VirtualHost Files With Document Roots as Given.

A.com

> Document Root : / or ROOT_OF_A

api.a.com

> Document Root : /api or DIRECTORY_NAMED_API_UNDER_ROOT_OF_A

Hope It will work! Let me Know if it does!